# How to allow eval in chrome extension version 3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm upgrading my chrome extension to manifest version 3. But, my extension uses `eval` in its content script. In version 3 I get the following error

```
Error in event handler: EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

I was able to fix this in version 2 as follows:

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

But this has changed and I tried many things

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "script-src": "self unsafe-eval",
    "unsafe-eval": "object-src self",
    "unsafe-inline": "self"
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is possible here, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check out the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#:~:text=directives%20may%20only%20have%20the%20following%20values). _"The **script-src**, ..., and worker-src directives **may only have the following values**: self, none, Any localhost source [...] CSP modifications for `sandbox` have no such new restrictions."_ You'll have to run your `eval` in a [sandboxed page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/) (or get rid of `eval`?)

Comment: I cannot get rid of eval :( [my extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oh-my-mock/egadlcooejllkdejejkhibmaphidmock) Users can mock APIs and to do that sometimes custom javascript can be provided too, which I can only evaluate with "eval"

Comment: People are discussing it here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/MPcq-feSK9c/m/8svP70a7BQAJ

Answer (score 5):

See if you can bypass it whith `Function( "return "+ toBeEvaluated )()` constructor; If that's blacklisted too see if they left `setTimeout( toBeEvaluated, 1 )` out. That would work as a substitution too.

But this fix is no avail - we need to fix the problem at its source.
Need to fix the superstition surrounding the eval command. People need to stop being afraid of power.

Comment: Google also blacklisted the `Function` constructor. But in this case, it's not about superstition or being afraid. Google tries to protect its users from malicious extension developers. There have been many cases of shady extensions in the Chrome Web Store which were stealing data from users using `eval`'ed code or external scripts. This cannot happen now that Google ensures that all the code an extension can run is within the source code it inspects before publishing it. And that's pretty good news.

Comment: I'm not following - what users ?! You are the client. You are the user. That's a client-side user script actually made to protect his browser in use and himself for the pages he must visit.

Comment: He's not developing a user script, but a browser extension. A browser extension, in most cases, is meant to be distributed to other users so that they can install it (e.g. AdBlock)

Comment: I thought they were called *Addons*, and to emphasize it - quite different from *Plugins*, whereas to my humble understanding :: *Extensions* are scripts that enhance the existing browser behavior, and are interpreted by that same browser.

Comment: new Function, setTimeout, eval, its all the same :(

Comment: Building an extension for developers and would like them to be able to completely modify a section of the extension by inserting their own code snippet. Sadly, this restriction makes it impossible.

Answer (score 5):

using `eval` or any other ways like `new Function` to execute code from a string is not supported in Manifest v3. It's against their updated policy. Manifest V3 does not allow arbitrary code execution.

ref: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code

However, a spokesperson from Google confirmed that **they plan to support** userscript managers (which depend on arbitrary code execution) in Manifest V3 before the Manifest V2 deprecation. Most likely end-user would need to enable some setting in order to allow the extension to run arbitrary code.

ref: https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/644#issuecomment-1140110430

Comment: I found a work around. `eval` will still work inside a sandbox!

Comment: oh, I haven't looked much into that but, is it possible to take a code string from the user and then run it in the contents DOM using this way? I'm trying to build a userscript extension

Comment: Yes you can. Checkout [this](https://calje.medium.com/how-to-use-eval-in-a-v3-chrome-extension-f21ca8c2160c) post in which I describe how to do it!

Comment: I followed the article and your extension code but using eval from sandbox still gives the error. ` EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".`

Comment: Did you add your sandbox files to the sandbox section of your manifest ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri yes I did, here's the [repo](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/superuser-extension) and [commit](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/superuser-extension/commit/946670ae1dc8b2fd9c34c4f8136dc0f6bd407086). you can run it as well using `npm run dev`

Comment: Fixed. I forgot something in my post :)