# Chrome-extension: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: eval, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, unsafe-eval

[waveform.js](https://github.com/mattdesl/codevember/blob/gh-pages/static/21.js)

I am trying to add the above js file in my chrome extension and getting this error: `Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"`

and here is my manifests settings:

"version": "0.6.2",
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self';",
"sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups allow-modals; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; child-src 'self';"
},

how to tackle this problem.

I tried [stackoverflow/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438506/how-to-allow-eval-in-chrome-extension-version-3), in this I remove eval/new Function from my js file but it did't work.

Comment: waveform.js uses `new Function` so it can't be used in an extension page script. You can use it in a [sandbox page or frame](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/) inside the extension page.